# I cannot increase the size of a table because it would exceed the maximum allowed in my publication. Any solution to make the data easy to read?

Tags: tables, size

First of all I'll describe my problem. I'm writing a publication in which I need to introduce three tables that have a lot of data. In order to fit the maximum space allowed, I made the tables smaller but this causes the tables to be very small and makes difficult to read the data. The tables can't overcome the width of the column.

Any tip or solution that can help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This depends on what your tables contain, the number of columns, the size of the text area, and so on. Could you post a (compilable)  example code?

Comment: at this general level this is an exact duplicate of the question referenced. If you try something and get a specific tex error or issue please open a new question with the example and the error that you get and someone will be able to help.